# Mutual exclusive equinox

Tags: code-golf, word-puzzle

1. Your sourcecode **must not** contain any of the characters it outputs (case sensitive).
2. Your program **must not** output more than 500 characters/bytes. 1 byte = 1 char. Newline counts as 1 character.
3. Your program should **not** take any input. (from user, filename, network or anything).
4. Your program must output words/phrases worth a total of **minimum 700 points** according to the following score table (case sensitive):

*Score table:*

```
me                        - 2   points
ore                       - 3   points
freq                      - 5   points
pager                     - 7   points
mentor                    - 11  points
triumph                   - 13  points
equipage                  - 17  points
equipment                 - 19  points
equivalent                - 23  points
equilibrium               - 29  points
unubiquitous              - 31  points
questionnaire             - 37  points
Mutüal 3xcLUs1ve_Equino>< - 400 points
```

- 4.1 Each word can be repeated but lose 1 point for each repetition (with exception for the last phrase worth 400 points, you **must not** repeat that in the output). For example:

four of `equilibrium` (in any place) in the output = `29+28+27+26` points.

- 4.2 Letters in the output can be used in more than one word, for example:

`equipager` = `equipage` and `pager` = `17+7` points.

This is code-golf, shortest sourcecode in bytes wins! Good luck, have fun!

Comment: Can my program contain the command "print" for example? because the letter 'i' appears in the source code and therefore most of the letters cannot be printed.

Comment: If your program contain the command `print` you cannot output any `p, r, i, n` or `t` and only get points for the word: `me` and I doubt you can reach 700 points using only that word ;). I foresee sourcecodes with most code in upper-case ;)

Comment: Is the fourth repetition of "me" worth zero points, or -1 point?

Comment: The fourth is worth zero points. No penalties (except for the 400 points phrase.)

Comment: Who wins? The shortest sourcecode or the best score?

Comment: It is code-golf, shortest code wins. The score is only part of the rules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Golfscript, 24 characters

```
"QUESTIONNAIRE"{32+}%36*
```

Way too easy.

36 repetitions of "questionnaire" = 36*13 characters = 468 characters.

36 repetitions of "questionnaire" = 37+36+...1 point = (37+1)(37)/2 points = 703 points.

Comment: Oh, darn! Thought I did the math correct, invalidating an option like this.. should have set it to 800 points instead ;) good work! +1

Comment: Then I would output some two words multiple times instead :-) Unfortunately, "equipager" is the only good overlap, and its repetition is worth way too few points.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I tried to weight the challenge so that the 400 points phrase actually should have been an option, but did the math regarding output-limit and score points wrong :(

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript, 391 chars

Could be golfed further.  Port of Jan Dvorak's answer; alerts `"questionnaire"` 36 times (although, hardcoded instead of via a loop).  `T` contains the string "true", `F` the string "false" and `O` the string "[object Object]".  From these (and `(1/0)+[]` = "Infinity"), `R` = "return" and `C` = "constructor" are constructed.  From this, we create a function `$` that does `alert("QUESTIONNAIRE"["toLowerCase"]())` and invoke it 36 times.

```js
T=!![]+[]
F=![]+[]
O={}+[]
R=T[1]+T[3]+T[0]+T[2]+T[1]+(0[[]]+[])[1]
C=O[5]+O[1]+(0[[]]+[])[1]+F[3]+T[0]+T[1]+T[2]+O[5]+T[0]+O[1]+T[1]
$=0[C][C](_[F[1]+F[2]+T[3]+T[1]+T[0]]+'("QUESTIONNAIRE"[T[0]+O[1]+"L"+O[1]+"w"+T[3]+T[1]+"C"+F[1]+F[3]+F[4]]())')
$();$();$();$();$();$()
$();$();$();$();$();$()
$();$();$();$();$();$()
$();$();$();$();$();$()
$();$();$();$();$();$()
$();$();$();$();$();$()
```

Comment: Neat! good job.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 6 (33 chars)

```
EVAL "SAY 'QUESTIONNAIRE'x 35".lc
```

13 chars * 35 repetitions = 455 chars total output
+ == 700 points; (3..37).elems = 35 repetitions.

Comment: How come `EVAL` works? Is it defined both in uppercase and lowercase (if so, why?!) or are function names case-insensitive in Perl 6?

Comment: @FireFly `eval` has been deprecated for `EVAL` not so long ago, to make it stand out you're doing special stuff I guess. Sorta like BEGIN, TOP, ... The change just happens to suit me here :)

Comment: I guess that makes sense, it just seemed kinda weird. I guess you got lucky. :P

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (88342)

http://pastebin.com/6UNTNXeT

alerts **Mutüal 3xcLUs1ve_Equino><** once + **unubiquitous** 12 times

Score: 706

Comment: You didn't even make an _attempt_ at golfing. None of `$_=;` are present in your output, so why not use them in the code?

Comment: Because JSfuck outputs only those 6 characters. Also, I don't think we can do better with JavaScript, because to output we can use alert(), console.log(), document.write() or element.innerHTML, and these functions contain letters that are too present in the required words.

Comment: `alert` == `this["alert"]` == `Function("return this")["alert"]` == `""["constructor"]["constructor"]("return this")["alert"]`, and the strings could be encoded similarly to how JSfuck works.  I'll post a submission to prove you wrong. :-)

Answer (score 1):

## C64 BASIC, 64 PETSCII chars

[image]

Should output 13 times the string "questionnaireunubiquitousequilibrium", with a score of:

equilibrium = 29+28+27+26+25+24+23+22+21+20+19+18+17=299
unubiquitous = 31+30+29+28+27+26+25+24+23+22+21+20+19=325
questionnaire = 37+36+35+34+33+32+31+30+29+28+27+26+25=403

**1027**.

(output is **481** chars long)